# Visual Studio 2008 - Disable .NET Framework debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

A rather strange question I know... I was previously using the .NET framework source stepping option (tools>options>debugging>general) within Visual Studio 2008.

Now although I have the option turned off, everytime I pause the debugger I start stepping into code I get taken into the .NET framework which takes an age to step back out of as by that point a lot of symbols have been loaded.

Has anyone else had this problem, and does anyone know how to turn it off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try selecting *Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)* in the same options menu (ie. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General).

This option gets disabled when you enable .Net Framework source stepping.

Comment: To be a little more thorough, you could make sure that the "Enable source server support" option is cleared (same menu as above) and also clear/uncheck any of the "Symbol file locations" specified in the Debugging->Symbols menu.

Comment: I actually had all that you suggested, however clearing the symbol cache folder as well seems to have done the trick. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are debugging the source code from .NET which downloads the appropriate PDB's and source from the web.  See this URL for an example:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx

You probably just need to reverse what ScottGu did to turn it on.